# Deleting Skype history not deleting from main.db

Tags: skype

I'm using Windows 7, and have deleted my history from Skype via privacy tab in the options. Whilst this has succesfully removed them from the Skype user interface, I've noticed that the main.db file in my `C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Roaming\Skype\` folder still contains the full conversation history. Is this a known issue? I'd expect that deleting the history would actually delete the history. Currently anyone with [Sqlite Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) or [Skyperious](https://github.com/suurjaak/Skyperious) can view the main.db file.

What's the best way to geniunely delete the history? Can I just delete the main.db file? I'm worried that this will contain data I do not want to delete. I guess I could delete everything from the messages table via Sqlite Browser. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you [change the history settings](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA392/where-can-i-find-my-conversation-history-in-skype-for-windows-desktop-and-what-can-i-do-with-it#9) to "no history at all", does that delete it?

Comment: Nope. I also noticed that there was a msn.db in the same folder. However the main.db did hold my latest conversations - so it's not like that's an old database file. A colleague who also deleted his history did have his history removed from the main.db file, and he also has an msn.db. Note that my Skype account is a Skype account, not a migrated Messenger account - so not sure what the msn.db is.